# Fullscreen (youtube, games) does not fill main screen, is shifted between two monitors. Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, xorg, xfce

I am trying to figure out where can I set position and size of "fullscreen view".

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, with XFCE on ThinkPad T400 (Intel HD4000 graphics card, 1280x800) with one external monitor (1920x1080). The external monitor is used as main, so when I play a game or, fullscreen a youtube video, I'd like it to fill that screen, instead the "fullscreen view" sits in between the two monitors.

I just checked and when fullscreening YouTube video it sits "in between" the monitors (right part of the image is absent from the left monitor) but the right monitor(laptop) still displays desktop.

When I have Chrome running on the right monitor(laptop).... you know what, I should probably draw it :)

---

### So this is my monitor setup

[My monitor setup http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3812442/My%20Actual%20Display%20Setup.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3812442/My%20Actual%20Display%20Setup.png)

---

### Screenshot of my normal desktop

[Screenshot of normal usage http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3812442/Normal%20Screenshot.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3812442/Normal%20Screenshot.png)

---

### When "fullscreened" from laptop screen

[When YouTube fullscreened from laptop screen http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3812442/Fullscreened%20from%20Laptop.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3812442/Fullscreened%20from%20Laptop.png)

---

### When "fullscreened" from my main 24" monitor

[When YouTube fullscreened from external LCD http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3812442/Fullscreen%20from%20Monitor.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3812442/Fullscreen%20from%20Monitor.png)

---

### When playing a game in fullscreen

[When playing a game in fullscreen http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3812442/Screnshot%20from%20Running%20Game.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3812442/Screnshot%20from%20Running%20Game.png)

---

As you can see it behaves differently for games and YouTube videos, games actually span to the other monitor but YouTube videos are shifted but the cut of part is not displayed on the other monitor. But not only that, even when "fullscreened" from laptop the image is shifted to the right (I think it should be shifted to the left if anywhere)!

Where and how can I set the "full screen" to be always on the main display?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to manually tweak xorg settings in the Screen and ServerFlags sections. Have a look at:
http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/X.Org/Dual_Monitors#Single.2C_Multi-headed_Graphics_Card

look at sections:
3.1 Fixed Dual-Monitors
3.2 Occasional Dual-Monitors
7 Xinerama

The same subject is also discussed in:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XineramaHowTo